# Error in nls model- singular gradient

Tags: r

I am trying to run a nls model for a pavement data ,I have different sections and I need to run a same model (of course with different variables for each section)
following is my model

```
data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
data
SecNum=data[,1]
t=c()
PCI=c()
t
PCI
for(i in 1:length(SecNum)){
  if(SecNum[i] == SecNum[i+1]){
    tt=data[i,2]
    PCIt=data[i,3]
    t=c(t, tt)
    PCI=c(PCI, PCIt)
  } else {
    tt=data[i,2]
    PCIt=data[i,3]
    t=c(t, tt)
    PCI=c(PCI, PCIt)
    alpha=1
    betha=1
    theta=1
    fit = nls(PCI ~ alpha-beta*exp((-theta*(t^gama))),
       start=c(alpha=min(c(PCI, PCIt)),beta=1,theta=1,gama=1))
    fitted(fit)
    resid(fit)
    print(t)
    print(PCI)
    t= c()
    PCI= c()
  }
}
```

after running my model I received an error like this

```
Error in nls(PCI ~ alpha - beta * exp((-theta * (t^gama))), start =     c(alpha = min(c(PCI,  : 
 singular gradient
```

My professor told me to use "nlsList" instead and that might solve the problem.
since I am new in R I don't know how to do that .I would be really thankful if anyone can advice me how to do it.
here is a sample of my data.

```
    SecNum  t    PCI   AADT     ESAL
    1       962  1  90.46 131333  3028352
    2       962  2  90.01 139682  3213995
    3       962  3  86.88 137353  2205859
    4       962  4  86.36 137353  2205859
    5       962  5  84.56 137353  2205859
    6       962  6  85.11 137353  2205859
    7       963  1  91.33  91600  3726288
```

Comment: indentation of your code will help

Comment: Have you already searched this site for `[r] nls singular gradient`?? What are you trying to do? With your sample data it seems like you are trying to estimate 4 parameters from one observation in your loop (ie when `i=1`). That's not statistically possible. This code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MrFlick yes I am trying to estimate 4 parameters by doing non linear regression using least square model.It's not one observation my data is very large I could not put all of them here,yes I have tried but I couldn't find any good answer maybe because I am new in learning R.

Comment: @innoSPG no but I will try that thank you